# *Why save magento visitor happen only when POST/PUT request?

Tags: magento2, security, request, get, post

I was involved in development of some service integration with magento. I provided this service callback URL. In controller/action I am creating a customer and making it logged in. But then I noticed an interesting thing:

On customer authorization magento does not correctly registering a visitor. Actually visitor exist, but it does not have customer_id (Looks like it's a guest).

Follow magento

> admin area > customers > now online

I didn't saw that customer there.

This happened because of following code:

```
/**
 * Save visitor by request
 *
 * Used in event "controller_action_postdispatch"
 *
 * @param   \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return  \Magento\Customer\Model\Visitor
 */
public function saveByRequest($observer)
{
    // prevent saving Visitor for safe methods, e.g. GET request
    if ($this->skipRequestLogging || $this->requestSafety->isSafeMethod() || $this->isModuleIgnored($observer)) {
        return $this;
    }
```

Following code: `$this->requestSafety->isSafeMethod()` returns true. Because 3rd party service followed our callback url with **GET** request.

**So what is the question:**

Magento did that check to exclude all get requests while customer walking throw pages?

Is it for security reasons? For example magento is expecting that method `$this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);`
should be called only from **POST** request?

If it's for security reasons, how somebody can exploit this?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know that too.

Modules using `customer_visitor` data and ajax webapi requests after magento upgrade now stopped to work. Shall we start using ajax POST requests to controllers back again? I don't get it.